# Trouble Requesting Data - Historical Traffic

Tags: here-api, here-traffic

I am trying to extract historical traffic data.

The documentation specified the time needs to be in the format: 2022-08-31T00:00:00-07:00 (midnight today).

My issue is that no matter what time I enter it only returns data associated with right now.

I have written a function that would extract traffic data every 15 minutes for a historical date and bounding box, however, it does not return unique data.

An example request URL is as follows:

https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?apiKey=#############&bbox=50.08518,-123.237232;49.447285,-123.049602&units=metric&responseattributes=shape&time=2022-08-31T00:00:00-07:00&minjamfactor=0

Could anyone assist with how exactly to extract historical traffic data for a given time?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience. But the current HERE traffic API V6.2/V7 provides the real-time traffic and incidents, not the historical traffic data.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that the api even accepts the time parameter then. Could you advise which service can be used to extract historical traffic data?